# How to filter data from Firebase database realtime with complicated nodes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now, I am trying to find specific user id by search by "phoneNumber" but his `phoneNumber` in specific node, so it's hard to reach or I don't know how I can find it. I want to get snapshot of this Info node.

Database structure

[image]

I am tried to search by query like that:

````
     Query q=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                    .orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo("8@gmail.com");
    ```
    and also tried this one 

    ``` 
    Query q=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Info")
                    .orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo("8@gmail.com");
````

But not worked also :(

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: sorry I forget t upload it ,  thank you @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those queries will work since in your first query you are missing the `Info` child and in the second you are missing the `Users` child. To solve this, please use the following query:

```
Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Users")
    .orderByChild("Info/phoneNumber")
    .equalTo("8@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

First things you need to do you have to make index in your firbase console rules 
like this

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
     ".read" : true,
    ".write" : false,
    "admin": {
        ".indexOn": "phone"
    }
  }

}
```

then write in you file where you are trying to get data by phone number

```
Query q=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                    .orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo("phoneValue")->getValue();
```